# Rails - Model Associations Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, models

I have these models:

```
class Profile
  has_many :projects, :through => "teams"
  has_many :teams, :foreign_key => "member_id"
  has_many :own_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => :profile_id
  has_many :own_teams, :through => :own_projects, :source => :teams
end

class Project
  belongs_to :profile, :class_name => "Profile"
  has_many :teams
  has_many :members, :class_name => "Profile", :through => "teams", :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Team
  belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Profile'
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I want to create model `Evaluation`. It will need the ID of the Project Owner, the ID of a Member of this Project, and the ID of the Project. Explaining better, The Owner of the Project will Evaluate all his members, one by one. And the members will evaluate **just** the owner of the project. The table Evaluation will have a lot of attributes plus those Ids mentioned before.

My question is: How would my models be to make it function with evaluation, and how would be model evaluation itself? `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`?

Thanks.

**Edited**

Shot in the dark

```
class Evaluations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluated, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "evaluated_id"
  belongs_to: :evaluator, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "profile_id"
end
```

Guess I won't need the ID from Project...

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't allow you to have extra attributes in the table so from the start is a no-go.

Comment: That is my initial though too. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You asked this same question in #6133064

Comment: The ID for the project might still be necessary in case you need to list all the evaluations for a single project. From what I understood of your description, it shouldn't be possible for a user to evaluate someone from a different project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help to build a Model in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104186/help-to-build-a-model-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

1. Project owner evaluates member performance for a project
2. Members will evaluate the project owner for his performance on a project
3. So, Evaluation has an evaluator, evaluee, a project, and other attributes
4. We also need to know the types of the evaluee and evaluator

Create 2 evaluation classes one for EmployeeEvaluation, one for ManagerEvaluation.  Use Single table inheritance.

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :evaluator, :evaluee
  belongs_to :project
end

class EmployeeEvaluation < Evaluation #project manager evaluation of employee
  def evaluator
    Manager.find(self.evaluator)
  end

  def evaluee
    Employee.find(self.evaluee)
  end
end

class ManagerEvaluation < Evaluation
  def evaluator
    Employee.find(self.evaluator)
  end

  def evaluee
    Manager.find(self.evaluee)
  end
end
```