# Help to build a Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Profile
  has_many :projects, :through => "teamss"
  has_many :teams, :foreign_key => "member_id"
  has_many :own_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => :profile_id
  has_many :own_teams, :through => :own_projects, :source => :teams
end

class Project
  belongs_to :profile, :class_name => "Profile"
  has_many :teams
  has_many :members, :class_name => "Profile", :through => "teams", :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Team
  belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Profile'
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I need to create model `Evaluation`. What I want to do is generate a link in `project#view` page for each member of the project, including the owner, in order to make an `Evaluation` The person will click on the link and evaluate the person related to this link. The owner of the `Project` will evaluate all the members, and all the members will evaluate the owner.

I have defined model `Evaluation` as following, but I think I miss something:

```
class Evaluations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluated, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "evaluated_id"
  belongs_to: :profile, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "profile_id"
end
```

Remembering that `Evaluation` table will have tons of attributes, that's why I'm going not going with `has_many_and_belongs_to_many`.

How can I create this model in order to do what I want and be able to acess all I need via `project#show` page?

Thanks!

**Edited**

Changes done:

```
class Profile
  has_many :evaluations, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => :evaluation_id
  has_many :evaluators, :through => :evaluations, :foreign_key => :profile_id
end

class Project
  has_many :evaluations,:foreign_key => "project_id"
end

class Evaluations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluated, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "evaluated_id"
  belongs_to: :profile, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "profile_id"
  belongs_to: :project, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => "project_id"
end
```

Comment: Is a new Evaluation created for each project a Profile is attached to?  If so it seems the Evaluation should `belongs_to :project` as well

Comment: The Project whole is just like a connector. Ex: I evaluated the owner of Project X because I was a member of Project X. But since the evaluation link will be in `project#show` I guess you might be right.

Answer (score 0):

You have your team and profile (member) associations a little messed up. A team has many profiles (members), and a profile (member) belongs to a team. Beyond that, you may just be over-complicating things. I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just call the Profile Model Member instead and keep things that much simpler?

That being said, you are doing a pretty complex set of associations. I would highly recommend you read the [ActiveRecord Associations doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) closely to get a firm understanding of how these things work, especially how primary and foreign keys are automagically determined.

I think below will get you what you want.

```
class Team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members,
    :class_name => "Profile"
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :team_leader,
    :class_name => "Profile"
end

class Profile
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_many :projects,
    :through => :teams
  has_many :owned_projects,
    :class_name => "Project",
    :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many :owned_teams,
    :class_name => "Team",
    :foreign_key => "team_leader_id"
  has_many :evaluations
  has_many :evaluations_given,
    :class_name => "Evaluation",
    :foreign_key => "evaluator_id"
end

class Project
  has_many :teams
  belongs_to :owner,
    :class_name => "Profile"
  has_many :members,
    :through => :teams
  has_many :evaluations
end

class Evaluation
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :evaluator,
    :class_name => "Profile",
    :foreign_key => "evaluator_id"
  belongs_to :project
end
```

In support of these model definitions would be the following tables/keys:

```
evaluation
  id
  profile_id
  evaluator_id
  project_id

teams
  id
  project_id
  team_leader_id

profiles
  id

project
  id
  owner_id

profiles_teams
  profile_id
  team_id
```

With this, you should be able to access collections/objects that you need to get your links right such as:

- project.members

  project.owner

  project.teams

  team.project

  profile.projects

  profile.owned_projects

  profile.teams

  team.members

  team.leader

  project.evaluations

  profile.evaluations

  evaluation.evaluator

  profile.evaluations_given

Note, also, that your **nested resources** are going to be just as complex, if you try to stay with a **RESTFUL** framework. Read up!